# Character to ASCII

Tags: java, char, ascii

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ASCIIvalue
{
    public static void main(String[] arg)
    {
        Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
        char ch;

        int ascii=(int)ch;

        System.out.println("Enter you any character: ");

        ch=input.next().charAt(0);
        System.out.println("The ASCII for this character"+ ch +"is" +ascii);

        System.out.println("");

    }
}
```

In the above code I am trying to get input(char) from user and then convert it to it's ASCII value but I get the error `Variable character might not have been initialized`

Comment: Please add the programming language to the tag, for this case add Java

Answer (score 1):

The error means that you are trying to access a variable that is not initialized.

```java
int ascii = (int) ch;
```

As you can see here, you are trying to access `ch` but it doesn't have a value.

To fix it, move the `int ascii = (int) ch;` below the input.

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ASCIIvalue
{
    public static void main(String[] arg)
    {
        Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
        char ch;

        System.out.println("Enter you any character: ");
        ch=input.next().charAt(0);

        int ascii = (int) ch;

        System.out.println("The ASCII for this character " + ch + " is " + ascii);

        System.out.println("");

    }
}
```

Output

```
Enter you any character:
a

The ASCII for this character a is 97
```

Answer (score 1):

Integer.valueOf('+') or Integer.valueOf(charInstance)

Comment: Perfect, idiomatic answer, which doesn't involve defining a new symbol.  Thank you very much.